# Where is android:persistent checked?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-source

I am doing work with AOSP and trying to create a system service. I am interested in the actual functionality of the android:persistent flag that can be set on an application. I am having a hard time finding some documentation on the android:persistent flag though given it gets used to infrequently.

I need to know what class that's part of AOSP is actually checking this flag and treating the service differently because I am getting weird behaviour from my persistent service. I feel like it may be doing more than just stopping my service from being killed.

So the question is, where does it get checked or what is the constant string representation for the flag android:persistent (if someone can just tell me what that string representation is, it won't be hard to grep and find all the places it comes up)

Comment: "I feel like it may be doing more than just stopping my service from being killed". I'm finding this to be true as well.  I can't seem to update my app because the previous, persistent version refused to get killed and overwritten. Did you have this issue as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well post the question and your answer shall immediately become obvious. The string literal seems to be in ApplicationInfo: FLAG_PERSISTENT and you can find it all on the grepcode page:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.java#ApplicationInfo.0FLAG_PERSISTENT